# Tabview content is overlapped

Tags: android, android-layout

My screen has 4 tabs with tablelayout. When I ask SQLite for data the tab is choosen due to **ugt** value.

When **ugt** equals 1 or 2 there is now problem - the data is separated between tab1 and tab2 and is shown normally.

But when **ugt** equals 3 or 4 the data is shown on ALL 4 tabs! And the data overlaps other data.

Here is the code:

```
        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndex(LeaderBase.UID));
            String name = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(LeaderBase.USERNAME));
            String money = String.valueOf(cursor2.getLong(cursor2.getColumnIndex(LeaderBase.USERMONEY)));
            String speed = String.valueOf(cursor2.getLong(cursor2.getColumnIndex(LeaderBase.USERSPEED)));
            String time = String.valueOf(cursor2.getLong(cursor2.getColumnIndex(LeaderBase.USERTIME)));
            int ugt = (int)cursor2.getLong(cursor2.getColumnIndex(LeaderBase.UGAMETYPE));


            TableRow row = null;
            switch(ugt){
        case 1:
             row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, tl1, false);
            break;
        case 2:
             row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, tl2, false);
            break;
        case 3:
             row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, tl3, false);
            break;
        case 4:
             row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, tl4, false);
            break;
        }
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            TextView tv4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            tv1.setText(name);
            tv2.setText(money);
            tv3.setText(time);
            tv4.setText(speed);

            switch(ugt){
            case 1:
                tl1.addView(row);
                break;
            case 2:
                tl2.addView(row);
                break;
            case 3:
                tl3.addView(row);
                break;
            case 4:
                tl4.addView(row);
                break;
            }

        }
```

Here is a screenshot.
[image]
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have selected tab content like this:

```
    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Без времени");
    tabs.addTab(spec1);
```

But tab1 was inside ScrollView1. So I changed all the strings

```
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
```

to

```
    spec1.setContent(R.id.ScrollView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the your switch block enters in default value because of unexpected value in ugt. Either check the code where you define ugt or you need to add a default value in your switch like this.

```
switch(ugt){
    case 1:
        //some code;
        break;
    case 2:
        //some code;
        break;
    case 3:
        //some code;
        break;
    case 4:
        //some code;
        break;
    default:
        //deafult code that happens when ugt is not the value from the other cases.
        break;
}
```

Print out the value of ugt so you can know for sure.

Comment: Done - the problem remains

Comment: What is the output of ugt?

Comment: The output is correct(1,2,3 or 4). Sometimes even the 1-st line in eachtab is overlapped shifted and mixed(i mean headings)